# Linux - Terminating AutoKey script using keybindings

Tags: python, linux, debian, autokey

Okay so I am new with AutoKey application on my **elementaryOS** device and I am just playing around with some custom scripts.

What I did find strange is that there is no *simple* option to terminate the running script.

So, is there any *nice **and** simple* method to achieve this.

Pardon the incompetency. ._.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no such method.

Autokey uses a simple mechanism to run scripts concurrently: Each script is executed inside a separate Python thread. It uses [this wrapper](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/blob/8c8488b3385a528570b9afbefa1a614b44237437/lib/autokey/service.py#L38-L48) to run scripts using the [ScriptRunner](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/blob/8c8488b3385a528570b9afbefa1a614b44237437/lib/autokey/service.py#L455-L470) class.
There are some methods to kill arbitrary, running Python threads, but those methods are neither *nice* nor *simple*. You can find answers for the generic case of this question on [Is there any way to kill a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

There is one *nice* possibility, but it is not really *simple* and it needs to be supported by your scripts. You can send a **stop** signal to scripts using the global script store.

Suppose, this is the script you want to interrupt.

```py
import time

def crunch():
    time.sleep(0.01)

def processor():
    for number in range(100_000_000):
        crunch(number)

processor()
```

Bind a stop script like this to a hotkey

```py
store.set_global_value("STOP", True)
```

Modify your script to check that value.

```py
import time

def crunch():
    time.sleep(0.01)

def processor():
    for number in range(100_000_000):
        crunch(number)
        if store.GLOBALS.get("STOP", False):
            store.set_global_value("STOP", False)
            break

processor()
```

You should add that code to each hot or long running code path.
This won't help if something deadlocks in your script.

Comment: Very insightful. Thank you, sir.

Comment: @luziferius  Why can't we use `store.get_global_value()` instead of `store.GLOBALS.get()` ? The latter only seems to work.

Comment: Lets see the code: https://github.com/autokey/autokey/blob/86e7a85d723753143f78e0684290a362bf6789c6/lib/autokey/scripting_Store.py#L46.  It returns None by default, thats why I wrote it to default to a clear False. But since None evaluates to False anyways, both ways should be fine.

Comment: line 8, in processor
    crunch(number)
TypeError: crunch() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given